# Close form on "lose focus" in VBA?

Tags: vba, autodesk-inventor

I have a VBA application that shows a form with controls on it.
I'm trying to find a way to close the form if the user clicks anywhere outside of it.

My VBA application is not in Excel, so I can't use Worksheet.SelectionChange Event

Comment: It would be better just make the form show Modal and give them a cancel button they can click.

Comment: If you're creating a form in Access, there is a form.LostFocus event.

Comment: @YowE3K: I'm simulating a drop-down menu. AutoDesk inventor allows me to create a button on it's ribbon bar and tie it to a macro. The macro calls form.show. If the user clicks anywhere outside of that form I want to close it.

Comment: Fair enough - that wouldn't get the users upset if it disappeared when they do something else - that would be standard behaviour on drop-downs so they would be used to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a brilliant solution to this dilemma here:

https://sites.google.com/site/msaccesscode/forms-1/howtoclosepopupnonmodalformwhenitlosesfocus

This method uses the pop-up form's Timer event to keep checking whether the pop-up form is the active form.  If so, the form stays open.  If not, it closes.